# Solve the complex equation $z^8+1=0$ and establish trigonometric identities

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

I am trying to understand a problem in complex numbers , the answer in the book doesn't tie up with what I am getting. The question is to solve the complex equation $z^8+1=0$ and establish a couple of trig identities based on the roots of the equation. The roots I get and the ones given in the solution are differing. Here's how I went solving the equation.

\begin{align*}
z^8 &= -1 = (\cos(\pi)+i\sin(\pi)) = (\cos((2k+1)\pi)+i\sin((2k+1)\pi))\\
\Rightarrow z &= \cos((2k+1)\pi/8)+i\sin((2k+1)\pi/8) 
\end{align*}

where $k = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ give the eight roots.

giving these values the roots work out as
\begin{align*}
&\pm ((\cos(\pi/8)+i\sin(\pi/8)) , \pm ((\cos(3\pi/8)+i\sin(3\pi/8)),\\
&\pm ((\cos(5\pi/8)+i\sin(5\pi/8)), \pm ((\cos(7\pi/8)+i\sin(7\pi/8)).
\end{align*}
but the book's solution list out the roots as
\begin{align*}
&\cos(pi/8)\pm i\sin(\pi/8) ,\cos(3\pi/8)\pm i\sin(3\pi/8), \\
&\cos(5\pi/8)\pm i\sin(5\pi/8), \cos(7\pi/8)\pm i\sin(7\pi/8).
\end{align*}

and proceeds to prove the following 2 identities based on the above roots.

$$\cos(\pi/8)\cos(3\pi/8)\cos(5\pi/8)\cos(7\pi/8) = 1/8$$

and
$$\cos(4\theta) = 8*(\cos(\theta)-\cos(\pi/8))*
(\cos(\theta)-\cos(3\pi/8))*(\cos(\theta)-\cos(5\pi/8))*(\cos(\theta)-\cos(7\pi/8)).$$

But I am stuck with roots not matching , please clarify where is the problem.

Thanks
Madavan.

Comment: please go through this link <https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference> to make your question more readable

Comment: I have fixed the latex. You can click "edit" to see what I did. But it seems there are some bracket missing in the last equation, please clarify.

Comment: Thanks Arctic Char , I will  fix the last equation soon.

Comment: Fixed the brackets in the  last equation.

Comment: Please consider that $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$ while $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$ to see that the two solution sets only represent a different pairing of the roots.

Comment: Thanks very much Lutz Lehmann,  got it for ex : -cos(pi/8)-i*sin(pi/8) = cos(7pi/8)-i*sin(7pi/8).